# trouble installing python from command prompt - lxml, libxml2, libxlst python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt

I'm trying to run the following command in my command prompt -

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I'm facing a number of problems that I have tried to solve but to no avail. The message I get from the command prompt is:

```
Collecting lxml==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyquery==1.2.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting cssselect>0.7.9 (from pyquery==1.2.10->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached cssselect-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Mohana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9bz1xoev\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp425xg1fhpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  Building lxml version 3.5.0.
  Building without Cython.
  ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

  Using build configuration of libxslt
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\lxml
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\python34\include -Ic:\python34\include /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
  cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
  lxml.etree.c
  src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
  Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  creating Users
  creating Users\Mohana
  creating Users\Mohana\AppData
  creating Users\Mohana\AppData\Local
  creating Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /TcC:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.c /FoUsers\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.obj
  xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.c
  C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitocb5oi7w.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, cssselect, pyquery
  Found existing installation: lxml 4.0.0
    Uninstalling lxml-4.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled lxml-4.0.0
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Mohana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9bz1xoev\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rjvm3d2l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.5.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\python34\include -Ic:\python34\include /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /TcC:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInity8a5suic.c /FoUsers\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInity8a5suic.obj
    xmlXPathInity8a5suic.c
    C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInity8a5suic.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of lxml
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Mohana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9bz1xoev\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rjvm3d2l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Mohana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9bz1xoev\lxml\
```

This is starting to get really frustrating because I can't understand how to set it right. I am using windows 10 on an Intel processor and I have Python 3.4. Help me sort this out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The ms-windows platform has some quirks (such as the lack of proper package management, and the requirement for extension modules to use the same version of the ms compiler that was used for Python itself) that makes installing software with dependencies a really painful experience compared to UNIX-like systems.

So on that platform I would advise people to use a Python *distribution* that does most of the heavy lifting. There are at least three distributions that I'm aware of:

- [ActivePython](https://www.activestate.com/activepython)
- [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)
- [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/product/canopy)

I've used Anaconda on ms-windows machines at work; it works fine and has a lot of packages available via its `conda` package manager. I cannot speak about the others, since I haven't used them.